# how to left align the first inline element put in body element in google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I am developing a web app by google apps script. I put inline element(span) at very first on body element. However, there is a gap between the very left edge of the screen and the left edge of the span element. And this gap is not slight.

I tried the same thing on [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HHerbert/ng48q6xr/), but there is no as long gap as implementation by google apps script.

**image**
the element in blue is span. the body is in red.
[image: the element in blue is span. the body is in red.]

**html**

```
<body>
  <span>test</span>
</body>
```

**styles can be seen on Chrome developer tool.**

for span:
[image]

for body:
[image]

I want to left align the span element on body. Please let me know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use CSS resets, at least `margin` and / or `padding` to `0`? Because if not, there will be a gap. Not sure why such a huge one - are you sure there aren't any conflicting rules - what do DevTools say about styles applied?

Comment: Show your css and fiddle

Comment: document.body.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style,textAlign="left";

Comment: @TheMaster I put the link for the fiddle. It is simple one and the code on fiddle works as expected with no problem.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for your advice. But it changed nothing.

Comment: @OlegValter I tried with margin and padding to 0 for both body and the span.

Comment: Could you show css box picture as seen on Firefox dev tools?

Comment: @Herbert - agreed with TheMaster - please, provide a screenshot or info on what styles are actually applied to the element (including inherited ones). I've even tried to reproduce - if that's *the only* styling you apply, there is no "gap" (apart from default `margin` of `8px` surrounding `body` tag if you don't use resets) / issue with aligning in Chrome & Firefox. Btw, what browser are we talking about here?

Comment: @OlegValter I am working on Chrome.

Comment: @TheMaster I added the picture of the style. Thank you.

Comment: hm, same setup looks fine for me: latest Chrome, no stylesheets, `span` element the first child of `body`. Could you check the "Computed" tab filtered by `left` and update the question?

Comment: There is 8px margin on the body. Try ``margin:0% !important;``. I'd also like to see computed styles.

Comment: @Herbert - it might also be of interest to see the `style` property values (ones that are set) on `span` and `body` elements that can be found in "Properties" tab of "Elements" panel. Other than that, you should've only seen the `8px` left margin

Comment: Thank you so much for your advises. I came up with the solution just now. I tried to create the same one from scratch on google platform, the same issue didn't occur then. So, I tried to remove code one chunk by on chunk. And then, I found there were full-width spaces causing this issue. Without your cooperation, I couldn't come up with the solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. That is, there are full-width spaces above the span element. I had full-width spaces in . I removed all the spaces from head. The gap on the left of the span disappeared.

I couldn't tell if there were spaces or not because the spaces can't be seen. I thought that all the spaces were put with half-width spaces which don't make any spaces on the html.

before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    　<base target="_top">
    <?!= include('css'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>test</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is one full-width space just before the `<base target="_top">`.

[image]

after:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('css'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>test</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: @TheMaster OK. I added the before and after to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. The answer makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can globally set margin and padding to 0 to removes all default margin and padding for every object on the page

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. yes, I applied it once and it removed default margin and padding from all elements. but the gap still remained on the left of the span as image above.

Comment: Can you share any live demo of your issue? It'll be much easier to provide you a solution.

Comment: I came up with the solution. Thank you so much for your advise.